# Append row below selected row in table

Tags: angularjs

I have table with list of my items. Each row has its own button "Show Details". When I click on that button I want to add new row below selected row in table. 
Lets say in my controller I have this data:

```
$scope.contacts = [
{first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', gender: 'm', phone: '(123)456 779'},
{first_name: 'Bar', last_name: 'Baker', gender: 'm', phone: '(123)456 779'},
{first_name: 'Foo', last_name: 'Tailor', gender: 'm', phone: '(123)456 779'}];
```

Then in my template view looks something like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>Actions</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in contacts">
    <td><button ng-click="showDetails(c)"</td>
    <td>{{c.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{c.last_name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My details row should be

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <div>
      First name: {{selected_contact.first_name}}<br>
      Last name: {{selected_contact.last_name}}<br>
      Gender: {{selected_contact.gender}}<br>
      Phone: {{selected_contact.phone}}<br>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Consider that in the table can have ~1000 so I don't want to add additional row after each one from ng-repeat, I'll have too many watchers if I use ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end directive.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|show_details|c1.first_name|c1.last_name |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|selected_contact.first_name             |
|selected_contact.last_name              |
|selected_contact.gender                 |
|selected_contact.phone                  |
+------------+---------------------------+
|show_details|c2.first_name|c2.last_name |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

In this picture c1 is selected and its details are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML or any mention of how the table is being created or what the data source is, it's not possible to give you more than a generic answer. Assuming that you're rendering the table using ng-repeat and that the data source is an array in your controller, you'd simply use array.splice() to insert a row in the array at the appropriate point and populate the data. Your HTML code would probably include 2 sets of  tags - one that handles the display you have now and another that is used to display the detail. You'd make use of one or all of ng-show, ng-hide or ng-if to display the appropriate  based on the type of data it contains.